# Target table cannot be same one for update clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name named 'employee'. Table creation code given below:

```
create table employee(name varchar(50),ph_no varchar(10),e_id varchar(5),pay_scale varchar(5),year varchar(4));
```

The table content is like below:

```
insert into employee(name,ph_no,pay_scale,year) values('AMIT','123456','PL-10','2019');
insert into employee(name,ph_no,pay_scale,year) values('AMIT','123456','PL-10','2020');
insert into employee(name,ph_no,pay_scale,year) values('AMIT','123456','PL-11','2021');
insert into employee(name,ph_no,pay_scale,year) values('AMIT','123456','PL-11','2022');

+------+--------+------+-----------+------+
| name | ph_no  | e_id | pay_scale | year |
+------+--------+------+-----------+------+
| AMIT | 123456 | NULL | PL-10     | 2019 |
| AMIT | 123456 | NULL | PL-10     | 2020 |
| AMIT | 123456 | NULL | PL-11     | 2021 |
| AMIT | 123456 | NULL | PL-11     | 2022 |
+------+--------+------+-----------+------+
```

Now I want to update 'e_id', first it will check whether the same e_id is in the table anywhere or not, if it is not in the table then only it will update the rows with given e_id, else it will not going to update.
So, my upgradation query is below:

```sql
update employee 
set e_id='0132' 
where concat_ws(',',name,ph_no,pay_scale)=concat_ws(',','AMIT','123456','PL-10') 
  and not exists (select e_id 
                  from employee 
                  group by e_id 
                  having count(*)>=1);
```

But it is giving the following error:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'employee' for update in FROM clause
> I have tried the below query:

```
update employee set e_id='0132' where
concat_ws(',',name,ph_no,pay_scale)=concat_ws(',','AMIT','123456','PL-10') and 
e_id not in 
    (select e_id from 
    (select e_id from employee group by e_id having count(*)>=1) as t);
```

But this also cannot update the table and showing below result:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

also tried the below code:

```
update employee set 
employee.e_id='0132' where 
employee.e_id not in (select * from
    (select f.e_id from 
    employee f inner join employee b on 
    b.name=f.name and b.ph_no=f.ph_no and b.pay_scale=f.pay_scale) as tmp) 
and employee.name='AMIT' and employee.ph_no='123456' and employee.pay_scale='PL-10';
```

but this also cannot update the table and gives below result:
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do , please publish your desired outcome as text.

Comment: plz elaborate your answer @Akina

Comment: if '0132' e_id is any e_id value in the table then update query will not perform else update query will perform @P.Salmon

Comment: Ok so you only expect 1 of the 2 rows for 'AMIT','123456','PL-10' to be updated , so on what basis would you choose the row to update?

Comment: no I'm expecting 2 rows for  'AMIT','123456','PL-10' will be updated. but first my query should check if e_id '0132' is present any e_id or not. if not present then update  'AMIT','123456','PL-10' rows. @P.Salmon

Comment: `NULL` doesn't play the way some people expect with `NOT IN`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24c176ff4d4e2c52309aaca14cc121c5   So, just put `WHERE e_id IS NOT NULL` in the sub-query.  Also, `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1` can be removed as it's always going to return a value of 1 or more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` doesn't play the way some people expect with `NOT IN`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24c176ff4d4e2c52309aaca14cc121c5   So, just put `WHERE e_id IS NOT NULL` in the sub-query.  Also, `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1` can be removed as it's always going to return a value of 1 or more...

```
update
  employee
set
  e_id='0132'
where
     name      = 'AMIT'
 and ph_no     = '123456'
 and pay_scale = 'PL-10'
 and e_id      not in (select e_id from 
                        (select distinct e_id
                           from employee
                          where e_id IS NOT NULL
                        )
                        as t
                       );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a0b036a7d1db9138e3ab29af3d346f8